# OnReceive() is not working for custom broadcast in parse push notification in android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have created my custom receiver for parse push notification in android. I have followed this link  http://ahirazitai.blogspot.in/2013/05/push-notification.html But inside the onReceive() what ever i print its won't. I down loaded this same project and imported it into eclipse android ran it. I can receive the parse message. When i receive the message my custom onReceive() won't work. I don't know why it doesn't reach. Can any body help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide your Parse initialization steps ? Did you added all the necessary entries inside manifest especially entry for your customreceiver class.

Comment: I wrote an example in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959811/how-to-override-onpushreceive-of-parsepushbroadcastreceiver/28960112#28960112 hope it helps!

Comment: Please check this sample https://github.com/Keshava11/parsecheck with custom receiver. Update keys in Application class and you are good to go