# How we can implement GCM as well as parse notification in same application?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

My app have one third party library, in this library implemented parse notification for notification.

But app required some notification from GCM.

So how can we implement both receiver in same project.

Any one have idea to implement both notification in same application ?

If possible then how ?

Please help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any reason why you need to use different push notification services?

Comment: yes parse use by library and gcm used by my app so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you just need to create a new a Broadcast Receiver to GCM.

Or even add a verification by action in your existing one. For example, in below's code I check if the action coming is a registration push from GCM or a push of mine by checking the intent action.

```
if (intent != null) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.w(TAG, "Registration Receiver called");
        if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(action)) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Received registration ID");
            final String registrationId = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
            String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");

            Log.d(TAG, "dmControl: registrationId = " + registrationId + ", error = " + error);
            // TODO Send this to my application server
        } else {
//Your code here
}
```

Your filter is gonna be something like...

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.myapp.push.ExternalReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.myapp.blablabla" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: if i create two different broadcast then both are working in same app? And both have same intent filter     
<action  android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
then also work or not ?

Comment: You can create as many Broadcast as you want, and yes, all of them will be listen to events at the same time. Why don't you create a action verification? Something like this String action = intent.getAction();

Comment: if we are use both receiver then get error like this :-


Unable to create service com.parse.PushService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.applicationContext()

Comment: What about creating an **action** verification in the same broadcast class?  Try to override  your onPushReceive() by doing this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959811/how-to-override-onpushreceive-of-parsepushbroadcastreceiver/28960112